# es6 exported object values not updated?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm exporting a factory function in ES6, which returns an object with properties.
When calling the factory, the object is created, but its values don't update.

Example:

```
// factory.js
let counter = 1;
let factory = () => {
    let increment = function(){
      counter++;
    }

  return { counter, increment };
}

export default factory;


// main.js
import factory from './factory';

let f = factory();
console.log(f.counter); // =>1
f.increment();
console.log(f.counter); // => stil 1, not 2?
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? Is it an ES6 feature, or something to do with the fact that I am using webpack and babel (es2015-preset)?

I have found this, but that doesn't describe the same use-case: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_imports-as-views-on-exports

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with ES6 or modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) are [passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).

```
let counter = 1;

let factory = () => {

  ...

  // The property `counter` in this object gets passed a value of the `counter` declared in the scope of `factory.js`.
  // It does not get a reference.
  return { counter, increment };
}
```

When you return the object from the `factory` function, its property `counter` is assigned a **value** from the `counter` declared in the scope of `factory.js`. This essentially means the `counter` property on the object received a **copy** of the value – there is nothing linking the value of the `counter` variable and the `counter` property.

```
let counter = 1;

let factory = () => {
  let increment = function () {
    // The `++` operates on the `counter` variable declared in the scope of `factory.js`.
    // There is no link between the value `counter` in the scope of `factory.js` and the `counter` as the property of the object returned.
    // As a result when the `counter` variable is incremented, the `counter` property remains the same as the value initially passed to it.
    counter++;
  };
};
```

When you increment the `counter`, you are incrementing the value of the variable declared in the scope of `factory.js`. The variable's value is a `Number` therefore being a primitive. Primitive values are passed by value so there is no link between the variable `counter` and the property `counter`.

Hopefully all that makes sense. If you want to do some more reading on this idea of **passing by value** (compared to **passing by reference**) you can see the following StackOverflow questions:

- [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)
- [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

At this point in time you might be asking **how can I fix this**?

Instead of incrementing `counter` you need to increment `this.counter`. Like this:

```
let increment = () => {
  this.counter++;
};
```

This works because the context of `this` is the object being returned from the function `factory`. The `counter` property is on the variable you assigned the result of calling `factory`.

Comment: thanks @wing, for you detailed answer!

it made me realise that it was the new destructuring syntax that was confusing me in: `return { counter, increment };`
i was getting the property and the value mixed up.

Comment: _"In JavaScript primitive types are passed by value."_ Everything is passed by value, but that's not relevant, because in the OP's example nothing is passed at all. _"the context of this is the function factory"_ The context is irrelevant and the value of `this` is the object returned by the factory.

Comment: @numblock _"it was the new destructuring syntax that was confusing me"_ That's not destructuring, it's an object literal.

Comment: @numblock no worries. Just to add to the comment from zeroflagl: what you are using there is not [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) but **[shorthand property assignment](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand)**.

Comment: @zeroflagL "_Everything is passed by value, but that's not relevant, because in the OP's example nothing is passed at all._" In the OP's example the value of the `counter` variable is passed to the object being returned. When I first read the question I interpreted it as the OP intending to increment a value on an object property which they believed was linked to the original declaration of a variable of the same name. Therefore I explained the cause of the issue – a misunderstanding on how the value of `counter` is passed to the object being returned and how to access it.

Comment: @zeroflagL "_The context is irrelevant_" The context is relevant because the OP is trying to access a data store called `counter`. This store sits in two contexts, with one being the object being returned. The OP was trying to access the `counter` property in that context.

Comment: @zeroflagL "_the value of `this` is the object returned by the factory._" yes that's correct. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @zeroflagL "_Everything is passed by value_" that's not technically true, see the SO question I linked in the answer: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: In the OP's example the value is assigned, not passed. And it's true: everything is passed by value. Instead of referring to an inaccurate answer you could refer to the specification. Or the correct answer (There is one). _"The context is irrelevant"_ may be a bit misleading. What it means here is that the **value** of `this` is the only thing that matters.